# How to properly manage web app behavior based on controlled list values from database?

Tags: php, database, laravel, software-design

*I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this question, so please advise if it should be moved.*

I am developing a web application based on Laravel whose main purpose is to provide an interface for a specific MariaDB relational database, which I didn't design or develop myself.

This database contains a number of so-called 'controlled lists' of vocabulary terms, in the form of tables with an auto-increment field and a string field holding the term.

One of these tables is used to control the possible statuses to set when creating or editing a record in the db. The terms to choose from (with a `<select>` in an HTML form) include *draft*, *complete* etc. and are retrieved from the table.

The problem is the following:

The app has a rudimentary system for user roles, since different type of users should have different privileges.

One such role is *reader* and it's only allowed to search for and view existing records, without editing anything. However, this user role should ***not*** be able to view records with a *draft* status.

The way I'm currently managing this looks somewhat like this:

```php
if (Auth::user()->is_reader && $record->status === 1) {
    abort(403,'Not enough privileges to view this record.');
}
```

It basically uses the ID for the *draft* value from the status list table to check the status of the record and act accordingly. I'm also using a similar system to exclude draft records from search results.

I don't like this because it relies on a specific ID value from the database, and although there is no way from the web interface to change the values in this specific table (list of statuses), the actual value could still change (or not?).

I've thought of first doing a query on the table to get the ID where the term is `LIKE %draft%`, but - although being more appropriate perhaps - I think I would still be relying on something that for some reason could change in the future (the term *draft*). Also, I suspect it would impact a bit on performance, though probably not much.

What would be a better way to approach this? Maybe don't use the database for this specific list of terms and put them in a config file?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If your list will be changed then use a class or settings of a config. But I don't like config for this things. The class can be defined in ServiceProvider and can be changed, also it helps an IDE. If your list can be changed then place your list in model. It is more cose. It works with an IDE and ease to find for other developers.

Comment: Thanks @OlegDmitrochenko. I don't think any other developer will ever work on this project, but I'd still like the code to be as maintainable and readable as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create an abstract class with some constants, and you use that const to refer to the desired value.

Something like:

```php
abstract class RecordStatus {
  // Some random names
  const STATUS_READABLE = 1;
  const STATUS_WRITABLE = 2;
}
```

Then when you need to use it:

```php
if (Auth::user()->is_reader && $record->status === RecordStatus::STATUS_READABLE) {
    abort(403,'Not enough privileges to view this record.');
}
```

This way you have:

- IDE autocompletion & inspection
- You can change the value easily (es. readable should be 3 instead of 1? just change it in the abstract class)

Comment: Accepted this answer as it effectively solves the problem.